# Android - openContactPhotoInputStream returns NULL for all contact photo IDs

Tags: android, null, image, contacts

After upgrading to Android 4.0 ICS, my app, which contains a contact list with images, stopped loading images for those contacts.

After debugging it seems the following line always returns NULL now.

```
 InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
```

I haven't changed the application at all, right after upgrading to ICS this started happening.

I have the permission READ_CONTACTS.

Does anyone know why this could happen? What could they have changed? Is this method deprecated or something?

The full code:

```
public static Bitmap loadContactPhoto(ContentResolver cr, long  id)
{
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
    InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
    if (input == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
}
```

Comment: doc says "Returns an InputStream of the photo, or null if no photo is present" Maybe that's the case?

Comment: The problem is that photos are present, at least in the stock Contacts application, the photos appear for Facebook and self-assigned photos.

Comment: Have you checked if other similar apps can display the images?

Comment: That's exactly the code i'm using for retreiving photo contacts in my apps and it's working. So, where does your ContentResolver and ID come from?